# Error FileNotFoundError [winError 2] anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

i get the error bellow, running the python code,
im running the program through anaconda cause it works only with python 3.6 or something, but i get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "inference.py", line 279, in
main()
File "inference.py", line 276, in main
subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\wav2lip\lib\subprocess.py", line 287, in call
with Popen(*popenargs, kwargs) as p:
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\wav2lip\lib\subprocess.py", line 729, in init
restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\wav2lip\lib\subprocess.py", line 1017, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

thank you for any help for solving the issue.

Note : i set the path on the system for the ffmpeg as well which is needed for the program to run, i dont know if this is the issue.

**command = 'ffmpeg -y -i {} -i {} -strict -2 -q:v 1 {}'.format(args.audio, 'temp/result.avi', args.outfile)**

Comment: It would really help if you showed us what `command` is.

Comment: the program that i use is https://github.com/Rudrabha/Wav2Lip

Comment: @JohnGordon i checked the file inference.py, thats the command command = 'ffmpeg -y -i {} -i {} -strict -2 -q:v 1 {}'.format(args.audio, 'temp/result.avi', args.outfile)                                       sorry for the previous post, i though you were asking about the command that i run

Comment: the result is stored in the temp, i can see it, but has no sound, i see only the video, and the lips movements.

Answer (score 0):

@Sollekram dakap

Just download and install ffmpeg from here https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/ffmpeg-release-full.7z
and add it to your system environment